# Transfer all data from one ledger to another in AWS QLDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-qldb

I have a QLDB ledger and it's full of tables now. There are a lot of InActive tables and because of these tables, I cannot create more tables because there is a limit of 40 tables per ledger.

Now for this, I need to transfer this ledger data to another. I was trying to achieve this by accessing both ledger drivers inside one node.js file and reading from one table then transferring data one by one to the other ledger's table.

Now there is also a limit of 40 documents within a transaction. So I was wondering if there was a way to do this easily. Because most Databases have a backup option.

I tried searching but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to transfer all data from one ledger to another at the moment. As [QLDB Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/disaster-recovery-resiliency.html) states:

> QLDB provides an on-demand journal export feature. Access the contents
> of your journal by exporting journal blocks from your ledger into an
> Amazon S3 bucket

> Automated restore for exports is not supported at this time. (...)
> However, a restore scenario is application dependent, where the
> exported records are presumably written back to a new ledger by
> leveraging the same or similar ingestion method.

So the only way to do it is manually.

[Here's](https://repost.aws/questions/QUa0C5ynGaTxKHgkEchk4FTg/qldb-restore-backups-option) a more detailed explanation about this topic