# Get qldb ledger table data in javascript object

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-qldb

So my issue is simple yet challenging. I am trying to transfer data from one ledger to another. Now for that, I am reading a whole table of data then creating an object for every document than inserting these documents one by one into the other ledger table

Ledger#1 Table1 -> get all data -> convert all data to array of objects -> transfer to Ledger#2 Table1 one by one

The problem is that I cannot create the object from the document. I do this manually by using prototype functions and reading field type and then creating a thing that is messy and causes some data to become null. So I was wondering if there was a better way that is less prone to errors.

I asked a [question of migrating ledger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73250575/transfer-all-data-from-one-ledger-to-another-in-aws-qldb) but had no luck in getting any response. Please help me in this.

Following is my code. Please copy and paste it inside an IDE so you can better understand

```
const getValueOfField = (field) => {
  const name = field.getType().name;
  switch (name) {
    case "string":
      return field.stringValue();
    case "int":
      return field.numberValue();
    case "null":
      return null;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

const enterDataInNewLedger = async (tableData, tableName) => {
  const awsProductionDriver = awsProduction();
  console.log(`Starting to insert data inside table ${tableName}`);
  try {
    for (const data of tableData) {
      await awsProductionDriver.executeLambda(async (txn) => {
        await txn.execute(`INSERT INTO ${tableName} ?`, data);
      });
    }
    console.log(`Done inserting data inside ${tableName}`);
    return { success: true };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return { success: false, message: err.message };
  }
};

const dataTransferOfTable = async (table) => {
  const prodDriver = awsProd();
  try {
    const allTableData = await prodDriver.executeLambda(async (txn) => {
      const result = await txn.execute(`SELECT * FROM ${table.name}`);
      const resultList = result.getResultList();
      let completeResults = [];
      for (const doc of resultList) {
        let newDoc = {};
        const fields = doc.fields();
        for (const field of fields) {
          newDoc[field[0]] = getValueOfField(field[1]);
        }
        completeResults.push(newDoc);
      }
      return completeResults;
    });
    const response = await enterDataInNewLedger(allTableData, table.name);
    checkForErrors(response);
    return { success: true };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return { success: false, message: err.message };
  }
};

const startDataTransferFromOneLedgerToAnother = async () => {
  try {
    for (let table of tableName) {
      const response = await dataTransferOfTable(table);
      checkForErrors(response);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
};

startDataTransferFromOneLedgerToAnother();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently I could've done this easily. I was just checking it and figured out the solution.

I can insert the whole fetched document and it will be same so my converted code is as follows

```
const { awsMainFunction: awsProd } = require("./awsProdConfig");
const { awsMainFunction: awsProduction } = require("./awsProductionConfig");
const { tableNamesAndIndeces: tableName, checkForErrors } = require("./utils");

const enterDataInNewLedger = async (tableData, tableName) => {
  const awsProductionDriver = awsProduction();
  console.log(`Starting to insert data inside table ${tableName}`);
  try {
    for (const data of tableData) {
      await awsProductionDriver.executeLambda(async (txn) => {
        await txn.execute(`INSERT INTO ${tableName} ?`, data);
      });
    }
    console.log(`Done inserting data inside ${tableName}`);
    return { success: true };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return { success: false, message: err.message };
  }
};

const dataTransferOfTable = async (table) => {
  const prodDriver = awsProd();
  try {
    const allTableData = await prodDriver.executeLambda(async (txn) => {
      const result = await txn.execute(`SELECT * FROM ${table.name}`);
      return result.getResultList();
    });
    const response = await enterDataInNewLedger(allTableData, table.name);
    checkForErrors(response);
    return { success: true };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return { success: false, message: err.message };
  }
};

const startDataTransferFromOneLedgerToAnother = async () => {
  try {
    for (let table of tableName) {
      const response = await dataTransferOfTable(table);
      checkForErrors(response);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
};

startDataTransferFromOneLedgerToAnother();
```